# Чем отличаются ConnectTimeout и ConnectionRequestTimeout?

Tags: java, spring

Есть пример запроса через `RestTemplate` поведение которого конфигурируется через `ClientHttpRequestFactory` и `RequestConfig`. При создании объекта `RequestConfig` задаются три разных таймаута: `ConnectTimeout`, `ConnectionRequestTimeout`, `SocketTimeout`. Объясните пожалуйста в чем отчичие, а то масло масляное получается. Особенно между `setConnectTimeout` и `setConnectionRequestTimeout`. А что это не одно и то же? Как может быть соединение в отрыве от запроса если мы основываемся на модели запрос ответ?

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());

private ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    int timeout = 5000;
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()

      // Вот тут.
      .setConnectTimeout(timeout)
      .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout)
      .setSocketTimeout(timeout)

      .build();
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder
      .create()
      .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
      .build();
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConnectTimeout` - [время на установку tcp-соединения](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html#getConnectTimeout())

`ConnectionRequestTimeout` - [время на получение соединения от менеджера соединений](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html#getConnectionRequestTimeout()). Наступление этого таймаута может говорить, например, о том, что пул исходящих соединений исчерпался.

`SocketTimeout` - [время максимальной неактивности соединения между двумя пакетами данных](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html#getSocketTimeout()). Как раз это и есть то время, в течении которого клиент ждет ответ от сервера

Answer (score 1):

Сначала HttpClient устанавливает tcp-соединение с сервером. Таймаут этого соединения определяется параметром `ConnectTimeout`. Обычно таймаут на данном этапе - это признак того, что сервер вообще недоступен по указанному адресу. После установки соединения клиент отправляет в это соединение http-запрос и начинает ждать ответа. Как долго он его будет ждать определяется параметром `ConnectionRequestTimeout`. Таймаут на данном этапе - это признак перегруженности сервера или возникших сбоев.

Comment: Спасибо! Тоесть под `ConnectTimeout` просто понимается тот первый запрос который устанавливает доступность ресурса, я правильно понял? А `SocketTimeout` это вероятно доступен ли сокет..?

Comment: HTTP - это протокол прикладного уровня, самый верхний в [стеке протоколов](https://goo.gl/Juvf9z). Чтобы отправить один http-запрос хосту придётся отправить целую кучу пакетов, включая установку tcp-соединения, [которая предполагает обмен 3-4 пакетами](https://goo.gl/Fo1jnM). С пониманием этой "матрёшки" придёт и понимание каждого таймаута.